# Loading ASPX pages in the extended monitor

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a web application in which the pages loaded from extended monitors loads in the primary instead of the extended monitor. Is there any specific settings required to handle this?

In IE and Firefox I'm facing this issue, but in chrome it loads in the extended monitor itself. 
I'm just doing a window.open from the page.

```
function openNewPage() {
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
}
```